# How to get a keypress to function the same as a click listener event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, keypress

I've made a simple little "game" where every time you click the picture of a balloon, it gets bigger until it "explodes" & then resets. Now I'm trying to get it to work the same only with the enter button. I want it to be able to do both the click and the keypress event, so I don't want to swap out the click event for the keypress. I'm not using any libraries, just plain JS. Here's my code so far:

```
function getRandomClicksUntilExplosion() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
}

const containerElement = document.getElementById("container");
const balloonElement = document.getElementById("balloon");
const explosionElement = document.getElementById("explosion");

let clickCount;
let clicksUntilExplosion;

function resetState() {
    containerElement.className = 'unexploded';
    balloonElement.style.transform = "scale(1)";
    clickCount = 0;
    clicksUntilExplosion = getRandomClicksUntilExplosion();
}
function getBigger() {
    const currentScale = balloonElement.style.transform.match(/(\d+)/)[0];
    const newScale = currentScale.toString() * 2;
    balloonElement.style.transform = "scale(" + newScale + ")";
}
function explodeBalloon() {
    containerElement.className = 'exploded';
}

function handleBalloonClick() {
    clickCount = clickCount + 1;
    if (clickCount <= clicksUntilExplosion) {
        getBigger();
    }
    if (clickCount === clicksUntilExplosion){
        explodeBalloon();
    }
    if (clickCount === clicksUntilExplosion + 1){
        resetState();
    }
}

resetState();

document.addEventListener("click", handleBalloonClick);
//reset the balloon on double click
document.addEventListener("dblclick", resetState);
```

I know I need to make a handle keypress function like I did with the handleClick, but I don't know how to get it to count the keypresses like it does the clicks, which is how it knows when to explode & then reset.

Here is the entire codepen if you need to see the entire thing:
https://codepen.io/lawana-mitchi-walker/pen/YzOzQpx

Comment: I would recommend against using "dblclick"; it's unreliable. And for "keypress" you can just add another event handler for "keypress" with the same handler function.

Comment: Keypress on an image? Do you want any keypress on the page? Bind the keyup or keydown event to the document

Comment: the dblclick is only there because it was one part of the "assignment" my mentor gave me.

Comment: I'm supposed to use the enter key specifically (and the spacebar to reset but I'll be able to figure that out once I get past this one)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    // code for enter
    handleBalloonClick();
  }
});
```

Comment: So that works for the most part, but it isn't behaving exactly like the click event. Specifically, it appears to reset back to the original size randomly

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final solution, it works great.

```
    document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
        var key = e.which || e.keyCode || 0;
        if (key === 13) {
            handleBalloonClick();
        }
        if (key === 32) {
            resetState();
        }
    })
```